# VBA Error Run time 13 error Type Mismatch can't find where it's happening

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching for hours trying to find how to fix my code but the problem is that I can't tell where the error is coming from! Please help!

I keep getting "run time error 13 Type mismatch"

```
Sub Mail_Every_Worksheet()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Range("D9").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

            sh.Copy
            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

            TempFileName = "Sheet " & sh.Name & " of " _
                         & ThisWorkbook.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With wb
                .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum

                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .to = sh.Range("D9").Value
                    .CC = ""
                    .BCC = ""
                    .Subject = "WEEKLY BOOKING REPORT " & sh.Range("K3").Value
                    .Body = "Hi " & sh.Range("D8").Value & vbNewLine & "Please find attached our updated weekly booking report." & vbNewLine & "If I can be of further assistance please do not hesitate to contact me."
                    .Attachments.Add wb.FullName
                    .Display   'or use .Send
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0

                .Close savechanges:=False
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing

            Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

        End If
    Next sh

    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: which line gives you this error?  Have you tried stepping though the code?

Comment: That's just the problem, it doesn't tell me which line. If I go into debug & step into, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is the `vbNewLine` actually `vbCrLf`? You might want to move the `With OutMail` block below the `With wb` block? Should you be attaching the temp file `TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr` instead of the `ActiveWorkbook`? Why you need it in `.xlsm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after your last `Dim` statement (or before the whole `Dim` block), put something like this:

```
On Error Goto ErrHandler
```

Then at the bottom of your procedure (immediately before `End Sub`), put something like this:

```
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Stop 'DO NOT LEAVE THAT IN PRODUCTION CODE!!!
        Resume 'pressing F8 when "Stop" is highlighted will take you to the error line.
    End If
```

Note that this is strictly a "debugging" error handler - should you have code like this in production, and run into an error, the VBA IDE would be brought up and shown to your user to debug. And if you leave `Resume` there, you'll have a nice infinite loop.

Also your `On Error Goto 0` will void the error handler, so replace it with `On Error Goto ErrHandler`.

Comment: Thanks! It was showing the error as the If sh.Range("D9").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then so I cnaged the formula in the cell & it works fine now! I can't thank you all enough! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it could be this simple: I think .xlsm was introduced with excel version 12 (2007) but your code is asking for Excel version to be less than 12 (which would not have an xlsm file type).  Does it help to change the code to "greater than 11"?

```
If Val(Application.Version) > 11 Then
    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
End If
```

Comment: Thanks but no, that didn't seem to do the trick. I think it's something to do with the cell references in the subject or body as I have used a similar code before without them?

Comment: It might not be related to your error, but it's a valid point: your condition is reversed, version < 12 means any version prior to 2010 (isn't 2007 version 11?), which means you're saving .xlsm with version 8 (Excel 2003), which is certainly going to [possibly] cause another kind of issue. I think the condition should be version >= 11.

Comment: @retailcoder: According to Ron de Bruin, Excel 2007 is version 12, and 2003 is version 11: [link](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win012.htm) so it probably should either be `>= 12` or `>11`.

Comment: @Chantel: I suspect you are running Windows 2003 with the Compatibility pack, so it doesn't notice the error in file format. I ran the code above in Excel 2010 and received a _Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed._ When I switched the code to '>12' the file saved. If this code will ever be run on other computers or versions of Excel you should probably change the code to prevent error, and include an `Else` statement with correct file format for lower versions.